# Close code generated win form with eventhandler

Tags: c#, winforms

How to close a code generated form when a listbox item is double clicked.

Here is my code

```
    private void btn_batchList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] batchList = BACH_Outward.GetOutBatchList(txtBranchId.Text, dtpHouseDt.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), cmbCLRTYPE.SelectedValue.ToString(), "T");
        if (batchList == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Form form = new Form();
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        form.MaximizeBox = false;
        form.MinimizeBox = false;
        form.Size = new Size(150, 325);
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        form.Location = new Point(this.Right - 200, this.Top + 100);
        form.Opacity = 50;
        form.Text = "Batch List";
        form.Move += new System.EventHandler(this.OnMove);

        ListBox BatchList = new ListBox();
        BatchList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(140, 315);
        form.Controls.Add(BatchList);            
        BatchList.DataSource = batchList;
        BatchList.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listBox_MouseDoubleClick);
        form.ShowDialog();
    }

private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        if (listBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var rect = listBox.GetItemRectangle(listBox.SelectedIndex);
            if (rect.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                // process item data here
                TxtBatchNo.Text = listBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
//want to close the popup form here.
            }

        }
    }
```

Now I want to close the popup form when user double clicks on an Item of the listBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close the window by obtaining a reference to the `Form` object and calling `Close()` on it:

```
((Form)listBox.TopLevelControl).Close();
```

However, I would strongly suggest creating a new form in your project so that it is its own class, and encapsulates all of its own logic.  It appears that you are creating a `Form` object directly from within another form and mixing the logic of the two forms together.  This is bad design and will make future maintenance more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare `form` object in a scope where both method can access it. then invoke the method `form.Close()` or change the visibility to hidden if you need to show it later.

Answer (score 0):

This is where a closure can be nice. Simply close over the form.

```
 BatchList.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, args) => {
   if (someCondition) {
     form.Close();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Anonymous delegate syntax may be nicer since the arguments are ignored: `BatchList.MouseDoubleClick += delegate { form.Close(); };`

Comment: Nice, I've been away from C# for a while, though this strikes me as older syntax. +1 for an example where `delegate` is more succinct than a lambda.

Comment: Lambda syntax is nicer typically when (1) you use one of the arguments or (2) you don't use any arguments and there are zero or one arguments.  Otherwise the older syntax turns out to be much more readable and easier to type.  (But of course, you can't use the older syntax where an `Expression<...>` is expected!)

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the lesson learned in syntax forms for lambdas is nicer from kotlin and groovy, as they do away with any explicit prefix to the block. `{ }` denotes a closure (inferred by passing), with an implicit `it` local representing the default argument in the case of list iteration, or if you pass to a method like Android's View.setOnClickListener. Admittedly, C# is a strong influence for Kotlin, at least, as they brought over extension methods from there.